# Prove Combinatoric Inequality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing, factorial

Prove that $$\binom{n}{k}\ge\frac{n^k}{k!}\left( 1- \frac{k(k-1)}{n}\right)$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$ where $n\ge k.$

I think that I've tried rewriting this about a million different ways now and I'm still not getting anywhere.  I've rewritten the inequality in a way that seems like it would be helpful, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\ge\frac{n^k}{k!} - \frac{n^{k-1}}{(k-2)!}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would begin :

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{k!}n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)=\frac{n^k}{k!}\underbrace{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)}_{A_{j,n}} $$

Now the name of the game is to show that $A_{j,n}$ is bigger than $\left(1-\frac{k(k-1)}{n}\right)$. Hint : develop the product.

Comment: To expand on the hint. Observe that $(1-x)(1-y) = 1-x -y +xy \geq 1-(x+y)$ for all $x, y>0$.

Comment: Should it not be $\frac{n^k}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^k \left( 1-\frac{j-1}{n} \right) $?

Comment: @ereHsaWyhsipS Yes I edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still struggling.  I see what you're getting at, but I can't get it to come out right for some reason.

Comment: @ereHsaWyhsipS, add your computations as an edit to your question and let me see if I can help you.